# Postgres: full join on two fields (data gap issue)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, null, full-outer-join

I have two sub-queries that create these tables:

```
 date      | name | data x
-----------+------+-------
2013-07-01 | a    |   2
2013-07-01 | c    |   3
2013-07-01 | d    |   1

 date      | name | data y
-----------+------+-------
2013-07-01 | a    |   13
2013-07-01 | b    |   16
2013-07-01 | d    |   20
```

I want to do a full join using both date and name as the join criteria. (Date is not limited to 2013-07-01, so really the date field and name field combined make an unique pseudo identifier field.)

Ideally the result should look something like:

```
 date      | name | data x | data y
-----------+------+--------+-------
2013-07-01 | a    |   2    |  13
2013-07-01 | b    |        |  16
2013-07-01 | c    |   3    |    
2013-07-01 | d    |   1    |  20
```

(Best if I can put in zeros for the null but that's can be dealt with later.)

I used a query similar to this:

```
select 
table1.date, table1.name, table1.dataX, table2.dataY
from table1
full join table2 on table1.date=table2.date and table1.name=table2.name
```

**Postgres is only bringing in fields that exist in both tables (so just the rows with names a and c in this example), which really defeats the point of a full join.**

I tried different way to troubleshoot, the only one that kind of worked so far is:

```
select 
table1.date, table2.date, table1.name, table2.name, table1.dataX, table2.dataY
from table1
full join table2 on table1.date=table2.date and table1.name=table2.name
```

returns:

```
 date      |date        | name | name | data x | data y
-----------+------------+------+------+--------+-------
2013-07-01 | 2013-07-01 |  a   |   a  |   2    |  13
           | 2013-07-01 |      |   b  |        |  16
2013-07-01 |            |  c   |      |   3    |    
2013-07-01 | 2013-07-01 |  d   |   d  |   1    |  20
```

There are workarounds to make this work when I use the data but really is not ideal. Any way to make the query return the desired result?

Losing quite some hair here. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Sorry I meant "on" when I typed "where". I did have joint conditions. In fact I suspect it's the two joint conditions that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `WHERE` clause, but a `JOIN` condition. The [`USING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) comes in handy:

```
SELECT the_date, name, t1.data_x, t2.data_y
FROM   tbl1 t1
FULL   JOIN tbl2 t2 USING (the_date, name);
```

To prove a point, it could be done without `USING`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.the_date, t2.the_date) AS the_date
      ,COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name) AS name
      ,t1.data_x, t2.data_y
FROM   tbl1 t1
FULL   JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.the_date = t2.the_date
                   AND t1.name = t2.name
```

Might be useful for related queries. The first one is more elegant, slightly faster and also standard SQL.

[**-> SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dbc1b/5) (demonstrating both)

Comment: "where" was a typo, my apologies.
But the real solution was doing `full join table2 using (date, name)` instead of `full join table2 on table1.date=table2.date and table1.name=table2.name`. It helped bringing all the data. 
Also in getting rid of the table reference in front of the two join fields, date and name.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks. The bottom of it was to avoid only calling table1 or table2 for the date and name field, since there are missing values. I spoke too soon about `using`.